# Using a form to append Nodes to XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm really new to PHP and Im trying to append Nodes to XML using PHP.

This is my comments.php file:

```
<?php 

$date = "http://jdrag.x10.mx/comments_file.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$commentt = $xml->addChild("comment");
$name = $_POST["cname"];
$email = $_POST["cemail"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$commentt->addChild("name", $name);
$commentt->addChild("email", $email);
$commentt->addChild("commentInside", $comment);

echo $xml->saveXML();

?>
```

My comments.html is:

```
<form action="comments.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="cname" />
Email: <input type="text" name="cemail" />
Comment: <input type="text" name="comment" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

As you can see my XML file is simple the `comments` tag: http://jdrag.x10.mx/comments_file.xml

But when I submit the form I get this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in /home/jdragx10/public_html/comments.php on line 5`

And because i'm new to PHP I really don't know what it means or how to fix it.
Thanks in advance to anyone who can fix my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to be using [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file).

The `simplexml_load_string()` function takes the XML document as a string whereas `simplexml_load_file()` takes the path to a file containing the XML, as you have.

---

You also have some problem with variable names, the path to the XML file is held in `$date` whereas you try to load the XML using the variable `$data`.

---

Finally, be sure to turn on (and to the maximum level) error reporting while you are writing your code.  The code above gives a notice message (*"Notice: Undefined variable: data…"*), not just a fatal error message.

Set the values `display_errors` and `error_reporting` to `On` and `-1` respectively, either in your `php.ini` file or using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set).

Comment: Question, is it possible to append Nodes and then save it to the actual file. For example, when I submit the form it shows me the results. But I would like it to edit: http://jdrag.x10.mx/comments_file.xml. As you can see im trying to create a comment system without using database. I will be submitting the comment to the xml file and then use AJAX to receive each `comment`. But right now its not doing what I want.

Comment: Yes, see your other question that got closed and the dozens (if not more) identical questions on the subject here. "Saving" the results is as easy as using `asXML(…)` instead of `saveXML()`. [Read the manual](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml) to find out how.